# fixing eclipse project setup

Tags: java, eclipse

I have somehow managed to get a really screwed up Eclipse project. I have been trying to debug a jUnit test, and I am unable to debug it properly. If I put a breakpoint in the class, then try to F6 to step over, the debugger is stopping on blank lines, commented out lines, etc etc. It's like the debugger is working on the wrong class. I am also getting a lot of failures in the class that don't seem related to it.

I have tried to delete and re-add my source folders, clean the project, etc. I am at a loss for what to do.

Thanks

Comment: I have this happen to me when the compiled test is from a different version of source.  Clean/Rebuild or manually delete class from the project usually fixes it for me.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up re-installing eclipse. I never did figure out the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds to me like the dependency sources that you have are out of sync. I've had this happen before.

A couple of questions:

1. Are you using maven? or...
2. Have you added dependent jars
   directly to your classpath?

If you are using maven then chances are you need to do some manipulation to get it to pull down the sources for the right artifacts. This could also be that you have some conflicts in your dependencies (check your dependency hierarchy view if you use maven+Eclipse).

If they are directly on your classpath, check that you have source jars as well, and possibly add those to your classpath.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your debug 'session' is out of sync with the source code. Sometimes eclipse is hard. But you need to refresh your source and recompile and build your project before debugging.

If that doesn't work, clean your project, close it and reopen it.

With some of my projects it is necessary that I remove every breakpoint and watches before the change in source gets picked up by the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by doing the following:

1. Removed the debug break points as suggested above.

cleaned the build folder and pulled the bundles from Ivy, then did the following in eclipse:

1. Removed my target platform and added it again (I'm using OSGi).
2. Cleaned all projects.

at this point, all my bundles are synced. But I was getting an error while validating bundles before starting the application. So then I closed Eclipse and re-opened it again.

Now everything works!

Answer (score 1):

The following steps helped for me:

1. Choose your Maven Project - right click
2. Choose Maven
3. Press - Update Project...
4. Tick necessary projects and click OK.